# How to insert a time column into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

Using Visual Studio 2010 and C#

`Table1`:

```
column         datatype
------------------------
Currenttime    time
```

How to insert a time value into `table1`?

Code

```
 string hr = txtHr.Text; 
 string min = txtMin.Text; 
 string time = hr + ":" + min;

 insert into table1 values(time)
```

Getting error

> Cannot convert from string to System.Timespan

while inserting into `table1`.

Need Code help

Comment: can you write the error here? is it convert error?

Comment: @Rapunzlo, Getting error as  cannot convert from system.datetime to system.timespan

Comment: You should ***always*** use **parametrized queries** and not concatenate together your own SQL statements (no exceptions!)

Comment: @marc_s, Its a predefined table, i cannot able to edit the structure, how to convert in c#

Comment: You don't have to change anything in your table - just change your **programming habits**

Answer (score 1):

You should ***always*** (no exceptions!) use parametrized queries instead of constructing your own SQL statement as a string! Just google "SQL injection" - it's a really horrible thing.... **stop doing that RIGHT NOW**

To use a parametrized query, you should get in the habit of using a pattern like this:

```
// Define your SQL query - WITH parameters! 
// And always specify the list of columns for your INSERT!
string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Table1(CurrentTime) VALUES(@TimeValue)";

// use the "using" blocks to properly protect your disposable connection and command
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=test;integrated security=SSPI;"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
{
    string hr = txtHr.Text; 
    string min = txtMin.Text; 
    string time = hr + ":" + min;

    // set the parameter value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TimeValue", SqlDbType.Time).Value = TimeSpan.Parse(time);

    // open connection, execute your INSERT, close connection
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need DateTime.Parse and not Timespan.parse , Timespan represents length of time

Comment: Tried, getting error cannot convert to system.datetime to system.timespan

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse to DateTime and not datetimepicker's itself, parse its value

```
DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.value)
```

Comment: Again getting a same error, i have edited my question added my code, please check and help me